# Compare cell value of first row of a dataframe to cell value of other rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a datafarme which has 50 columns and above 200 rows with binary values:

```
 
a1  a2  a3  a4  ….. a50
0   1   0   1   ….. 1
1   0   0   1   ….  0
0   1   1   0   ….  0
1   1   1   0   ….  1
```

I would like to compare cell values of first row to other rows one by one and make the 51th column which output the non-matching cells as below: (since the first row is not compared with any row it will get a nan value)

```
 
a51
NAN
a1,a2,…,a50
a3,a4…,a50
a1,a3,a4,…
```

I am not sure how to do this efficiently. I have not find any answer similar to this question. Sorry if I am asking repeated question. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Setup**

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2,size=(200,50)),
                  columns =[f'a{i}' for i in range(1,51)])
```

---

### [`Series.dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dot.html) + [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) and [`Series.str.rstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html)

```
df['a51']=df.iloc[1:].ne(df.iloc[0]).dot(df.add_suffix(', ').columns).str.rstrip(', ')
```

**Time comparision for 50 columns and 200 rows**

```
%%timeit
df['a51'] = df.iloc[1:].ne(df.iloc[0]).dot(df.add_suffix(', ').columns).str.rstrip(', ')
25.4 ms ± 681 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)


%%timeit
a = df.to_numpy()
m = np.where(a[0,:] != a[1:,None], df.columns, np.nan)
pd.DataFrame(m.squeeze()).stack().groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)
41.1 ms ± 4.16 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)


%%timeit
df.iloc[1:].apply(lambda row: df.columns[df.iloc[0] != row].values, axis=1)
147 ms ± 18.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Can you try with a **large** df (just out of curiosity)? :)

Comment: `size =(5000,5000)`--> `%%timeit
df['a10001']=df.iloc[1:].ne(df.iloc[0]).dot(df.add_suffix(', ').columns).str.rstrip(', ')
12.7 s ± 1.18 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`,
`%%timeit
a = df.to_numpy()
m = np.where(a[0,:] != a[1:,None], df.columns, np.nan)
pd.DataFrame(m.squeeze()).stack().groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)
13 s ± 492 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`,
`%%timeit
df.iloc[1:].apply(lambda row: df.columns[df.iloc[0] != row].values, axis=1)
34.2 s ± 2.14 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

```
import numpy as np

a = df.to_numpy()
m = np.where(a[0,:] != a[1:,None], df.columns, np.nan)
pd.DataFrame(m.squeeze()).stack().groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)

0    a1, a2, a50
1    a3, a4, a50
2     a1, a3, a4
dtype: object
```

---

Input data:

```
print(df)

   a1  a2  a3  a4  a50
0   0   1   0   1    1
1   1   0   0   1    0
2   0   1   1   0    0
3   1   1   1   0    1
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the list of column names that don't match the first row:

```
df['a51'] = df.iloc[1:].apply(lambda row: df.columns[df.iloc[0] != row].values, axis=1)
```

200 rows is small enough so that `apply(..., axis=1)` is not a performance concern.